# How to compare three values in a array and merge?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i merge array with the same value?

I have three array which are  $participants, $conferance_participants and $contacts

i want to compare values with this three array and merge

for example :

if $participants['calleridnum'] == $conferance_participants['uid'] == $contacts['name']

i want the output to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 1
            [test] => yay
            [uid] => 1
            [channel] => deze
            [name] => 1
            [limit] => 1
        )

)
```

this is my code so far:

```
<?php
$participants = [
    [   'calleridnum' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay' 
    ]
];
$conferance_participants = [
    [   'uid' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'channel' => 'deze'
    ]
];
$contacts = [
    [   'name' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'limit' => 1
    ]
];

foreach ($participants as $participant=>$p) {
    foreach ($conferance_participants as $conferance_participant=>$c) {
        foreach ($contacts as $contact=>$cs) {


        if (($p['calleridnum'] == $c['uid']) && ($c['uid'] == $cs['name'])) {


                 foreach ( $c as $key=>$val ) {
                     if (!isset($p[$key])) {
                    $participants[$participant][$key] = $val;
                    }
                } 

            } 
        }
    } 
}

print_r( $participants );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `array_merge()` , but you still have to consider the different values with the same key (eg. the values of key 'test' )

```
if (($p['calleridnum'] == $c['uid']) && ($p['uid'] == $c['name'])) {
    $participants[$participant] = array_merge(
        $participants[$participant],
        $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant],
        $contacts[$contact]
    );
}
```